# How can I round these corners on my custom shape?

Tags: swiftui

I have made a custom 'slanted' rectangle that I would like to become a rounded 'slanted' rectangle. Here is a picture so far:

[image: shape]

```
struct SlantedRectangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 30))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

How can I round the top left and top right corners?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For rounded corners, you can use [`addArc`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgmutablepath/2427140-addarc) method of `Path`.

```
struct SlantedRectangle: Shape {
    let slanted: CGFloat
    let radius: CGFloat
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width - radius, y: slanted))
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.width - radius, y: slanted + radius), radius: radius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), clockwise: false)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: radius))
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: radius, y: radius), radius: radius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 270), clockwise: false)
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
}
```

Now create your `SlantedRectangle` like this.

```
SlantedRectangle(slanted: 30, radius: 30)
```

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOwMe.png)